# Condition for co-planarity of 2 lines.

Tags: vectors

Suppose we have 2 lines
$$\begin{align}L_1&= \frac{x-x_1}{a_1}=\frac{y-y_1}{b_1}=\frac{z-z_1}{c_1}\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}L_2&= \frac{x-x_2}{a_2}=\frac{y-y_2}{b_2}=\frac{z-z_2}{c_2}\end{align}$$
I know for 2 lines to be co-planar we must have,
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        x_1-x_2 & y_1-y_2 & z_1-z_2 \\
        a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
        a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

is equal to 0. However I was wondering if this observation is correct.

In 3D 2 lines can be parrallel,intersecting or skewed.

If they are parrallel, they must line on the same plane. If they are skewed they cannot lie on the same plane and if they intersect,they must lie on the same plane.

- So if the 2 lines interesct at a point they must lie on the same plane.
- Also if the minimum distance between them is 0,they must interesect,hence lie on the same plane.

Are my observations correct or am I missing something?

Comment: They can also be coincident, intersecting at all points, with no defined plane of intersection.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean the same thing as being parallel?

Comment: It means your parallel and intersecting cases overlap, which I'd call an error in your observations rather than an error in your conclusion.

Comment: Alright I got it. Thanks.